# d3.js: insert g elements at a certain location

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For example if i have this

```
  <div>
    <g class="one"></g>
    <g class="two"></g>
    <g class="three"></g>
    <g class="four"></g>
    <g class="five"></g>
  </div>
```

If i want to insert another `g` with class `new` in between the the two `g` with class `three` and `two`.

Resulting in

```
  <div>
    <g class="one"></g>
    <g class="two"></g>
    <g class="new"></g>
    <g class="three"></g>
    <g class="four"></g>
    <g class="five"></g>
  </div>
```

These work:

```
d3.select("div").insert("g", ".three").attr("class", "new");
d3.select("div").insert("g", ":nth-child(3)").attr("class", "new");
```

But it will not work if i have this and want to insert a `g` with class `new` at where the line is. (I've used lines as I'm not sure if i will explain it correctly)

```
  <div>
    <g class="one">
      <g class="two">
        <circle></circle>
      </g>
      <g class="one">
        <circle></circle>
      </g>
      <g class="one">
        <circle></circle>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="one"></g>
    ------------------(this is where i want <g class="new"></g>)--------
    <g class="two"></g>
    <g class="one"></g>
    <g class="one"></g>
  </div>
```

Is it possible to insert it by only counting the number of `g` at the level under `div`. E.g between the 2nd and 3rd `g` tag.

I've tried something like:

`d3.select("div").insert("g", "div > g, g:nth-of-type(3)").attr("class", "new");`

I figured out a workaround:

```
d3.selectAll("g").filter("div > g").classed("temp", true);
d3.select("div").insert("g", ".temp:nth-of-type(3)").attr("class", "new");
d3.selectAll(".temp").classed("temp", false);
```

But it seems really inefficient.

Comment: since when is SVG `g` an allowed direct child tag of a `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
d3.select("div").insert("g", ".three").attr("class", "new");
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOREXN?editors=1001).

If you wanted to insert after the nth element, rather than after a specific class, you can do something like:

```
d3.select("div").insert("g", ":nth-child(3)").attr("class", "new");
```

If you need even more flexibility (maybe you have other elements in that div other than `g`), you can insert before the nth `g` like so:

```
d3.select("div").insert("g", "g:nth-of-type(3)").attr("class", "new");
```

**EDIT**:

Still unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but here is my last attempt:

```
d3.select("div").insert("g", "div > g:nth-of-type(3)").attr("class", "new").append("text").text("new ");
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmKbxz)

This will insert the new `g` before the third `g` element that is a direct child of the `div`. It has nothing to do with the classes, I don't know why you mentioned classes in the first place, especially if you knew they were not unique but your example makes it appear as if that were so.

You should read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks! your last solution works. can you please explain to me why the other codes don't work on the updated code chunk?

Comment: They work in the codepen, but maybe not for your case, I just didn't add any text to the new graph, but you can inspect the page and see it's there.

Comment: [fiddle](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdgrpZ?editors=1001). I am guessing this will not work because the third `g` is in another `g` which is one level lower. In this case how can i still use `nth-of-type(3)` to obtain the same result (between `two` and `three`) without knowing how many more `g` there are before `three`?

Comment: Yeah they were more so just examples, so you can get a feel for what can be done. If this works fine check it off, otherwise I'll edit to make it more clear

Comment: So is it possible to locate the `g` with class `three` with `nth-of-type(3)` when there are more `g` elements before it.

Comment: Why do you need that? The first solution should work so long as there is only one `g.three` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmKbxz

Comment: I actually have multiple elements with the same class and I am cloning objects for animation so i have a lot of similar objects. Id be really handy if it is possible. Excuse me for not providing a correct example. Ill edit it.

Comment: Yes because that is an entirely different question

Comment: Edited.I apologize for the hassle. I'd rather edit than asking a new question.

Comment: It's still not completely clear what you want... I'm assuming you only want to consider `g` tags that are direct children out the outer `div`. But you're still talking about the class in your example, and that actually conflicts with what you're asking. I've updated my question one more time and linked you to more resources because it seems you really need to get a hand on the basics first.